# Messages asks for two factor authentication in iCloud settings

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, icloud

I updated to iOS 12 on my iphone SE and didn't like what it was doing so I reverted to iOS 11. Now my wifi iPad, also iOS 11 won't sync messages and in iCloud settings if I try to slide Messages on it asks for two-factor authentication. Any idea how to revert this so it just works again? It was bugging me when I updated the phone to iOS 12.

Comment: What do you mean "so it just works again"?  Can you please [edit] your question to clearly state what the problem is and what you've already done to solve it?  It's very difficult to understand the problem with the current wording.

Comment: When you upgrade one device to iOS 12, all other connected devices lose access to cloud stuff like messages and each device asks for two-factor authentication. I don't want this and other issues I found with iOS 12 so I reverted my iPhone back to iOS 11, which is what the iPad was always on. But iPad won't work with Messages as in the iCloud settings when you try to click the slider it says "you must enable two-factor authentication". iOS 12 must switch something on in the cloud and I just want to go back to before.

Comment: Two-factor authentication is a requirement of iOS11.  Once you changed iOS versions, you're now required to use 2FA.  I don't believe it matters if you just want to go back to what you had, you still need to use 2FA now.  You can also go back to a previous backup you took while you were on iOS 11 (you do have a backup, right?).

Comment: I think moving to iOS 12 switched something in the cloud for my iPad as no matter what I do it wants 2FA. Everything new breaks something old. I might switch off autoupdates and live in a cave from now on.

Comment: I've finally got it to work. iCloud is odd and sometimes just needs a bit of time before stuff resets itself. Its back to allowing two-factor. Phew.

Comment: @fsb Actually, that can't be the full story. I have iOS 11 and iOS 12 installed on various devices and do not use 2FA on any of these (due to a personal preference). In my case I'm not using 2FA at all (i.e. on ***any*** device), so that may have something to do with it. But the point I'm making is that two-factor authentication isn't a *requirement* in iOS 11 or iOS 12.

Comment: @Rusty The most likely cause is that after upgrading to iOS 12 you would have been prompted to use 2FA as part of the setup process, and without thinking you probably enabled it. I'm pretty sure I've seen a question and answer here that explains how you can disable it again. When I have some time I'll see if I can find it and will post a link to see if it helps.

Comment: @Monomeeth According to Apple, 2FA is required from iOS 11 forward.  iCloud accounts that already existed were moved to 2FA automatically when the iOS upgrade occurred. If you're not using it then at some point you disabled it on at least one device for the Apple ID.  Multiple sources have been reporting this requirement for over a year.

Comment: Thanks @fsb - I’ve never used 2FA (so haven’t had to disable anything). Maybe that’s why this issue has been off my radar. I do get prompted from time to time to enable 2FA, but nowhere near as often as I used to. I’ve also checked my wife’s and kids devices (all iPhones on iOS 12, iPads a mix of iOS 11 and iOS 12) and 2FA is off on all of them as well. So it still seems something different about my setup is allowing me to avoid 2FA. Hmm, I do use a separate iCloud account to the Apple ID I use for iTunes and the App Store, so that may partly explain things. :)